# swig and building project with visual studios 2017 command line

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio

I need to create a .pyd from a .cxx file that was generated from SWIG.  I am bit of a noob when it comes to VS2017 and command line and I'm hoping for a little help.

Here is what I have done so far:

SWIG Setup for Windows

1). Download anaconda (using python 3.6 x64 version)

2). Download VS community version

```
- installed all the c++ extensions
```

3). Downloaded the FGDB API (windows 2017):

https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/blob/master/FileGDB_API_1.5.1/FileGDB_API_1_5_1-VS2017.zip

4). Set the Python Environment Variables:

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include

PYTHON_LIB: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs\python36.lib
```

5). Download and unzip Swig

6). Add swig path to PATH environmental variable

7). Download the file-geodatabase-api files from google hosting or github.
    https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/file-geodatabase-api-python-wrapper/source-archive.zip

8). Create folder: C:\fgdb_code

- There should be a .i, .py and a make file in the folder

9). Place the files from step #7 in this folder

10). Unzip the file from step #3 in folder from step #8

```
c:\fgdb_code\FGDB
```

Generating the .cxx file

11). Open a command line window as administrator (admin might not be needed)

12). Navigate to the c:\fgdb_code folder

13). Run: swig -python -IFGDB/include -c++ filegdbapi.i

```
This generates a .cxx file
```

```
    Output Message:

```
FGDB\include\Util.h(819) : Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored).
FGDB\include\Util.h(838) : Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored).
FGDB\include\Util.h(843) : Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored).
FGDB\include\Util.h(849) : Warning 312: Nested union not currently supported (ignored).
FGDB\include\Geodatabase.h(307) : Warning 503: Can't wrap 'FileGDBAPI::CreateGeodatabase' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
FGDB\include\Geodatabase.h(308) : Warning 503: Can't wrap 'FileGDBAPI::OpenGeodatabase' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
FGDB\include\Geodatabase.h(309) : Warning 503: Can't wrap 'FileGDBAPI::CloseGeodatabase' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
FGDB\include\Geodatabase.h(310) : Warning 503: Can't wrap 'FileGDBAPI::DeleteGeodatabase' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
```

```

Generating the .pyd file from VS 2017

This is where I get stuck.
I've tried creating a new VS project for generating a DLL, but I can't seem to get the interface to work (i am finding the VS studios interface a bit daunting).  Is there a way to do this via command line without creating a project?  If so, can someone provide some guidance on how I can do this?
I should only need the .i and .cxx file to compile the code.

**UPDATE**
Generating the .pyd file from VS 2017

14). Open Visual Studios

15). Select File -> From Existing Code

16). Select c++

17). Enter the following:

```
- Project file location: folder from step #8

- project name: filegdbapi

- Check add files (should be checked by default)

- Click Next
```

18). For project type: Dynamically linked library (DLL) project

19). Press Finish

20). Build the project

Fails with:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: filegdbapi, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>XSD : error : The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider, CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located.
1>
1>If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".
1>Done building project "filegdbapi.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The libraries are incompatible with your version of Visual Studio

Comment: Are you sure, it says VS2017

Comment: I mean, with your exact version, for example in the old 14.1 MSVC version you couldn't make your program portable, in this case the libraries are incompatible with the compiler

Comment: is there a way to figure out what I need to make this thing compile?

Comment: The only thing i can tell you, is update your visual studio to the latest version